# Bootstrap Right Hand Sidebar Not Long Enough

Tags: twitter-bootstrap-3

Apologies if this is quite basic but I am having issues with a bootstrap right hand sidebar not taking up the entire right hand area. The images in a separate div area are overlapping this sidebar. If I add more content to the sidebar it goes to crap. 
How can I get the two smaller images to occupy the same width as div above which is col-med-8. Maybe I am looking at this the wrong way, I am learning HTML CSS etc so I am confused a bit.
Any Help would be greatly appreciated.

here is the links for site

http://vigilant-bardeen-58c461.bitballoon.com/

here is dropboxlink

https://www.dropbox.com/s/1i0qfpijgekvdfj/newsweek.zip?dl=0 .

Thanks
Neil

Comment: Hi Neil, it would help us answer your question if you included an image of your problem (not just a link to the site), a diagram or mockup of how you'd like them to look, and an example of the relevant code (HTML and CSS) in the body of the question. Also, no one is going to download an unknown .zip file to look at your code. Please embed the relevant code in the body of the question.

Comment: [Don't share your code via a zipped file in dropbox.](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/266715/2745495). Please read [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Hi Guys, many thanks for the kind responses and pointers. My first question so all help is greatly appreciated. 
This is html page as it stands: 
https://i.gyazo.com/3fa499185401bc57fc3424d7c6f9ffce.jpg.

the right hand side bar only seems to take up the space of the list elements instead of occupying the whole right sidebar area.

Answer (score 0):

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <!-- Head -->
  <head>
    <title>Newsweek</title>

    <link href="css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="css/navbar.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="css/main.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="css/sidebar.css" rel="stylesheet">
  </head>

  <!-- Body -->
  <body>
    <!-- Navbar -->
    <nav class="topnav navbar navbar-inverse navbar-static-top" role="navigation">
      <div class="container">
        <div class="navbar-header hidden-xs">
          <a href="#" class="pull-left">
            <img class="visible-sm visible-lg" src="images/logo/logo_lg.svg" alt="">
            <img class="visible-md" src="images/logo/logo-sm.svg" alt="">
          </a>
        </div>
        <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-left nav-items visible-md visible-lg">
          <li><a href="#">U.S.</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">WORLD</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">BUSINESS</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">TECH & SCIENCE</a></li>
          <li><a href="#" class="glyphicon glyphicon-search"></a></li>
        </ul>
        <div id="navbar" class="navbar-collapse collapse">
          <a href="#" class="pull-left">
            <img class="visible-xs" src="images/logo/logo-sm.svg" alt="">
          </a>
          <!-- Smaller Screen Nav Bar -->
          <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right hidden-lg hidden-md">
            <li class="divider-vertical"></li>
            <li class="dropdown dropdown-style">
              <a href="#" id="search-box" class="dropdown-toggle glyphicon glyphicon-search" data-toggle="dropdown"></a>
              <div class="banner-width-set">
              </div>
            </li>
            <li class="divider-vertical"></li>
            <li class="dropdown dropdown-style-sm-hamburger">
              <a href="#" id="hamburger" class="dropdown-toggle glyphicon glyphicon-menu-hamburger" data-toggle="dropdown"></a>
              <div class="banner-width-set">
              </div>
            </li>
          </ul>
          <!-- lg Screen Nav Bar -->
          <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right visible-lg visible-md">
            <li class="divider-vertical"></li>
            <li class="dropdown">
              <a href="#" id="circular-image" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">
                <div class="banner-subscribe-to">
                  <div class="wrapper">
                    <p><img class="img-circle" src="images/navbar/nav-bar-img.jpg">
                      <span>Subscribe <br> To Newsweek</span>
                    </p>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </a>
            </li>
            <li class="divider-vertical"></li>
            <li class="dropdown dropdown-style">
              <a href="#" id="map-marker" class="dropdown-toggle glyphicon glyphicon-map-marker" data-toggle="dropdown"></a>
            </li>
            <li class="divider-vertical"></li>
            <li><a href="#">Sign In</a>
              <div class="banner-sign-in">
              </div>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </div>
      </div>
    </nav>

    <div class="container main-content">
      <div class="row">

        <div class="col-md-8">
          <img src="images/main/main_main.jpg" class=" main-image img-responsive"   alt="news reader">
        <!--Main-->
        </div>

<div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-4 sidebar ">
        <!--Side Menu-->
        <h1 class="headlines-title text-left">Latest Headlines</h1>
          <ul>

            <li class="latest-headlines"> <span class="bullet-text">Watch: Gorilla Gives Birth to First Son Moke</span></li>
            <hr>
            <li class="latest-headlines"> <span class="bullet-text">Woman Charged Over Attack on Pregnant Service Woman</li>
               <hr>
            <li class="latest-headlines"> <span class="bullet-text">'Sick and Tired of Being Babied': Embiid Lashes out</li>
               <hr>
            <li class="latest-headlines"> <span class="bullet-text">Syrian Independence Day: Facts on Freedom from France</li>
               <hr>
            <li class="latest-headlines"><span class="bullet-text">‘The Terror’ Episode 5: The Tuunbaq Attacks</li>
               <hr>
            <li class="latest-headlines"><span class="bullet-text">White Evangelical Support for Trump Grows</li>
              <hr>

            <li class="latest-headlines"><span class="bullet-text">White Evangelical Support for Trump Grows</li>


          </ul>
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-block">See All Headlines</button>
        </div>

      </div>
    </div>

    </div>

    <!-- ******* more content ***** -->

      <div class="container more-content">
        <div class="row">

        <div class="col-md-8">
          <h3> <span class="country-header text-center" >U.S</span></h3>
          <h4>JUSTICE DEPARTMENT TO FORCE REFORMS</h4>
          <h5>Residents of Ferguson have waited nearly a year for their city to adopt the agreement. </h5>
        <!--Main-->
        </div>
        <div class="container more-content">
          <div class="row">
          <div class="col-md-6">
            <div class="content">
              <img src="images/main/main1.png" alt="man on sinking car" class="img-thumbnail">
            </div>
          </div>

        <div class="row">
          <div class="col-md-6"></div>
           <div class="content">
          <img src="images/main/main2.jpg" alt="asian university photo" class="img-thumbnail">
        </div>
         </div>

</div>


    <!-- Bootstrap core JavaScript
    ================================================== -->
    <!-- Placed at the end of the document so the pages load faster -->
    <script src="js/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```